# How to set up a one to one phone call from twilio for an iphone app?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to make a call using twilio from my iPhone App. But not able to install the server file.Following is the link of tutorial file

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client

Comment: Do you have any errors? What is going wrong for you?

Comment: I am not able to install server.py file using the command python server.py.  I am getting following error                                                         
ImportError: No module named flask.
I have also tried to use ngrok . I am getting the error                       connection  was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:5000.

Comment: What error are you getting, can you edit your question with all the detail you can provide, please?

Answer (score 0):

The [Mobile QuickStart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/setup) app relies on the Flask framework. Seeing as you received the `ImportError: No module named flask` message, you'd have to [install Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) to start.